# Is "else if constexpr" after a non constexpr if, legal?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Writing the `else` clause to an `if constexpr` condition is straightforward:

```cpp
if constexpr (my_condition)
{
}
else // No special  syntax, this branch is constexpr
{
}
```

In the situation where **my initial `if` is not a constexpr condition**, I've been seeing code like this:

```cpp
if (some_condition)
{
}
else 
{
  if constexpr (my_condition)
  {
  }
}
```

Though it may look strange, I think the following code is equivalent:

```cpp
if (some_condition)
{
}
else if constexpr (my_condition)
{
}
```

since C++ doesn't really have an `elif` clause but merely an `else` chained to another `if`. Is it correct to write `else if constexpr` after a non constexpr `if`?

Comment: `else if` isn't one thing, it's `else <statement>`.

Comment: @chris Isn't my comment about `elif` at the end of the question the same point?

Comment: Yes, it is valid.  `else` can be immediately followed by any valid statement.

Comment: Let me put it this way, `if constexpr` doesn't have its own grammar production. It's "implented" by the C++ standard as an optional keyword in a "regular" if. And it simply introduces a constraint and some additional behavior in templates. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, it ain't the preprocessor. Discarding the branch doesn't leave you with `if (a) { } else <syntax error>`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks, the second comment made the penny drop. I've been trying to find proof that it won't create invalid syntax or even try to "absorb" the next statement in case the "if constexpr" dissapears (by absorb I mean put it under the orphaned `else`)

Comment: @LorahAttkins - I figured that might be the issue. I haven't found an explicit mention, but it's an emerging property of the grammar. You aren't dealing with a token soup, the else's statement is unconditionally the `if constexpr`, regardless of additional semantics.